# Katalon Studio error: Unable to navigate to authenticated page (Root cause: java.lang.Exception: Unsupported browser (only support IE, FF, Chrome))

Tags: google-chrome-headless, katalon-studio

I am trying to launch a test case using Chrome headless. I authenticate with this line of code:

```
WebUI.authenticate("url", "name", "password", 10)
```

but it gives the error: Unable to navigate to authenticated page (Root cause: java.lang.Exception: Unsupported browser (only support IE, FF, Chrome))

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://docs.katalon.com/display/KD/%5BWebUI%5D+Authenticate), the first parameter should be an URL, not just 'url'.

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar problem on the [Katalon Forums](https://forum.katalon.com/discussion/2534/authenticate-method-doesn-t-detect-btnok-in-a-popup). There is a proposed workaround (for an example url of https://dev.mcdonalds.konoss.net/):

```
WebUI.openBrowser('https://Username:Password@dev.mcdonalds.konoss.net/')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with **FailureHandling**

`WebUI.authenticate("url", "name", "password", 10, , FailureHandling.OPTIONAL)`